# XPath get node by value

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I have this XML:

```
<root>
  <experiment accessCount="1" downloadCount="1">alfa</experiment>
  <experiment accessCount="1" downloadCount="1">beta</experiment>
</root>
```

And I would like to detect if the node experiment with value alfa exists.
But this PHP code is returning to me all values.

```
    $this->xml = simplexml_load_file("data/stats.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
    $node = $this->xml->xpath("/root[experiment='alfa']");
```

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query the node value with `text()`:

```
$node = $this->xml->xpath("/root/experiment[text()='alfa']");
```

Comment: Note the small difference between this and the other answer. Using `.` will combine (it combines becuase the `=` operator forces atomization) all children, however deep, using `text()` will combine only the first level text children. This can be important if you have to deal with mixed content in your `experiment` element.

Comment: No, you shouldn't be using text(). Use `[. = 'alfa']`. as advised by @kjhughes. Using `text()` will fail, for example, if the text contains XML comments.

Answer (score 5):

**Your XPath,**

```
    /root[experiment='alfa']
```

**says:**

> *Select the `root` element that contains an `experiment` element with string value equal to `'alfa'`.*

There is one such `root` element in your example, and it contains ***both*** `experimental` elements.

---

**This XPath,**

```
    /root/experiment[.='alfa']
```

**says:**

> *Select the `experiment` element with string value equal to `'alfa'`.*

And will select the one `experiment` element you seek.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this code

```
/root/experiment[matches(.,'alfa')]
```

will work absolutely

Comment: `matches()` requires XPath 2.0 and is also overkill when testing for literal equality.